# XQuery expression to reutrn items based on comparison on their attributes

Tags: xml, xquery

Suppose the XML is

```
<s>
  <e id="2" role="x">
  <e id="3" role="y">
</s>
<s>
  <e id="2" role="y">
  <e id="3" role="x">
</s>
```

I am looking for an XQuery to return all `s` where they have element`e[@role="x"]` and element `e[@role="y"]` as any descendant and the first element `id` is less than the second element id.

For example in the case above, it should only returns the first `s`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as long as you don't have more than one of each role per s:

```
let $d := (
<s>
  <e id="2" role="x"/>
  <e id="3" role="y"/>
</s>,
<s>
  <e id="2" role="y"/>
  <e id="3" role="x"/>
</s>
)
return (
  $d/descendant-or-self::s[.//e[@role="x"] and .//e[@role="y"] and
     .//e[@role="x"]/xs:integer(@id) < .//e[@role="y"]/xs:integer(@id)]
)
```